# How to extend primary partition? Linux

Tags: linux, centos

My primary partition is running out of space (/dev/sda1). The main partition (/dev/sda) having much more free space. I want to transfer space from (/dev/sda) and extend to (/dev/sda1) partition which is my primary partition and have all linux boot, kernel etc files.

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 204.8 GB, 204803670016 bytes,400007168 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size(logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size(minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   199997439    99997696     Linux
```

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 if your comment isn't about requesting a clarification of a technical point, then it is not a comment that needs to be posted. Next time, please keep your unrelated opinions to yourself.

Comment: `/dev/sda` is not the "main partition", but the whole disk, and `/dev/sda1` is part of it. You should simply extend `/dev/sda1` with any tool you like (which could mean deleting and then recreating it at the same sector offset/start -- 2048, but larger than 48G), and then **after** you have resized the partition, resize the filesystem residing on it with `resize2fs` or similar. I suggest you do a `dd if=/dev/sda of=saved_mbr count=1` before, so you could restore the original partition if anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that need doing: re-size partition, then re-size file-system.

To make this easier there is gparted. It is a GUI, it will do both. You can not do it when the file-system is in use, so boot off of a live CD/USB. You can download the gparted OS. A small live OS with just a minimal tool kit, including gparted.

## Alternatively

You have a root partition that is large (mine is only 20G).

Add a `/home` partition. This could fill the rest of the disk, you will not have to reboot. Just create the new partition, and mount it (gparted can do all of this, but you will have to install it first). Next copy you old `/home` to the new `/home`. You can use bind mount, to expose the, possibly`hidden`/home`. (you probably want to logout of any account with data that could be lost, while doing this).

## With the command line

It is a long time since I did it this way, as I always have to look it up (I don't do it enough. I use the command line for most things, but I don't do this much so use the GUI).

You have to do two things:
 - resize the partition.
 - resize the file-system (with the command that you have found).

You should not be using the file-system, when you re-size it. So will need a live CD/USB.

## What I would do.

I would add a `/home`. I always to this, as it makes upgrades to new OS easier (replace OS, keep `/home`). You can also make links from other parts of `/` into `/home` E.g. `/opt` → `/home/system/opt`,`/usr/local` → `/home/system/usr-local` …

Comment: thanks for your answer. is there any other way to do this? with linux command. for example  command is resize2fs. Run sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1 - this form will default to making the filesystem to take all available space on the partition.

Comment: Sorry that last comment does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are using your physical device as physical without any logical layer.
It is better to use logical volumes as it will help you manage your devices without touching the partition part.

When defining volume group, it give you possibilities to add physical devices to the group making abstraction to your logical partitions.

Later you can extend the logical volume with space available on volume group.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Unix & Linux. While your suggestion is correnct in principle, the OP has _not_ configured LVM, so it cannot use it to expand its partitions. So I'm going to vote to close the answer. Please se also [answer].

Comment: What you say is true, but not an Answer. If you showed how to re-do their current setup with LVM, that'd be one thing, but saying "don't do that" is not a good Answer to "how do I do that?"

Comment: @MrShunz: that a goooood encouragemnt to a new comer like me. I did read the how to and here a tip for you too:"Always be polite and have fun
It’s fine to disagree and express concern, but please be civil. "