# How to move disk space from /dev/sda to /dev/sda1?

Tags: linux, centos, partition

I have a Virtual machine using centos 7 with 200GB disk.For some reason my layout is:

```
df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                100GB  95GB  5GB
```

Running fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 204.8 GB, 204803670016 bytes,400007168 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size(logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size(minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0006c283

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   199997439    99997696     Linux
```

I would like to increase my space on my partision /dev/sda1.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information. What exactly means "Virtual Server"? A virtual machine you can modify as you like? A virtual server offered by a hosting provider? Can you boot a live system from an ISO image? How did you set up the system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extend primary partition? Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500129/how-to-extend-primary-partition-linux)

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you are tying to extend the partition.  To do this:

1. Resize the allocated partition. eg: `cfdisk /dev/sda` and select the option to resize the partition.
2. The OS should update automatically, but just in case you can call `partprobe /dev/sda`
3. Resize the file system.  eg: for the ext file systems `resize2fs /dev/sda1`

As long as you are extending the partition (not shrinking) it should be safe to do this with the system running.  But do backup everything.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to extend my partition:

1. delete the partition and create a new one in its place

```
root@rescue ~ # fdisk /dev/sda

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1

Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1):
Using default value 1
First sector (2048-199999487, default 2048):
Using default value 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2048-199999487, default 199999487):
Using default value 199999487

Partition #1 contains a ext4 signature.
Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o: N

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 102.4 GB, 102399737856 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12449 cylinders, total 199999488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00051eb3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   199999487    99998720   83  Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered!

Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

2.  resize the filesystem

```
# resize2fs /dev/sda1
resize2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/sda1 to 24999680 (4k) blocks.
The filesystem on /dev/sda1 is now 24999680 blocks long.
```

3. reboot

Comment: Be very careful with resizing a file system this way.  With GPT partitioned hard drives you may not get back the same unique ID for the partition when you re-create it.  This can cause boot problems.  This is why I recommend `cfdisk` resize over an `fdisk` delete and re-create.